# scheduling exclusive, uniform length, interval constrained events

Tags: algorithms

*n* one-day long events are to take place over *m* days. Each event has a simple date range *r1-r2*, such that *0 < r1* and *r2 <= m*, in which it can be scheduled to take place.

Determine whether it's possible to schedule each event exclusively on its own day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [cumulative constraint](https://glossary.informs.org/ver2/mpgwiki/index.php?title=Cumulative_constraint) with $p_i=c_i=1$ for all $i$ and $C=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you think this is a duplicate question?